# Unable to match patterns from one file line by line with contents of other file | bash shell

Tags: grep

I have a file1.txt containing text like:

> 123
>  456
>  789

I need to search these strings line by line in another file2.txt like this:

> ```
> "123" This is line 1
> "456" This is line 2
> "789" This is line 3
> ```

Matching lines need to be echoed or redirected to file3.txt

I tried couple of ways:

```
while read -r line; do 
grep "$line" -c file2.txt 
done < file1.txt
```

This doesn't give me any matches, although there are some.

I also tried grep like this:

`grep -f file1.txt -c file2.txt`

which unfortunately doesn't work either.

For all three matches, output should have been:

```
1
1
1
```

I am new to shell scripting. Could someone please suggest what is wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: works on this side.

Comment: Hello, @Jetchisel, may I ask which method from above works for you? Also, it would be great if you could give me any pointers for my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @Ninad, could you please check my answer once if that helped you here?

Comment: @Ninad: Can you clarify logic of your output? Do you want counts of matches in `file2`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are ok with `awk` could you please try following then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($2 in a)' file1.txt FS="\"" file2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                             ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1.txt is being read.
  a[$0]                              ##Creating array a with index current line here.
  next                               ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
($2 in a)                            ##Checking condition if 2nd field is present in array a then print the current line from file2.txt
' file1.txt FS="\"" file2.txt        ##Mentioning Input_file names here, where setting FS as " for file2.txt
```

***2nd solution:*** With changing Input_file(s) sequence of reading.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($0 in a){print a[$0]}' FS="\"" file2.txt file1.txt
```